# in laravel add data into database from foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

i try to put data on two different table of database with one controller store function i face problem in second table when i safe data of foreign key.

```
$pdata['admissions_cnic']=$admissions->cnic;
$details=$admissions->details()->create($pdata['details']);
return redirect('/index');
```

[image: when i dd admission_cnic not save on details]

[image: data not enter]

[migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXsWa.png)
[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peP1m.png)

[admission model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaKQC.png)

Comment: can you show your migration and model codes?

Comment: Yes I attach pictures

Comment: I mean migration file that laravel migrate db from it. sth like 20120201_create_detail.php in databalse/migration directiory.

Comment: yes i attach picture of migration file

Comment: and what's admissions model content?

Comment: Can you post it as code instead of image?

Comment: And can you please post a [larger portion of the first code block](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know what the variables contain?

Answer (score 0):

As per your given image, your `admissions_cnic` value is not in `$details` array.
your data should be like this

```
$pdata['details'] = [
  "DOB" => "dd-mm-yyy",
  "admisssions_cnic" => foeign_key
];
```

Please try!

Comment: $pdata=request()->validate([ 
                         
                         'details.DOB'=>'required',
                         'details.admission_cnic'=>'$admissions->cnic',                                    
      response::array:1 [▼
  "details" => array:1 [▼
    "DOB" => "2021-04-15"
  ]
]

Comment: Not successful    $pdata['details'] =request()->validate([
         'DOB' => 'required',
         'admisssions_cnic' => '$admissions->cnic',

Comment: what is the proper response you're getting?